# Why does the peak magnitude of the cardiac pacemaker action potential not increase to levels closer to the Ca++ equilibrium potential?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, cardiology

it does for K+ and Na+ but not calcium? why?

Answer (score 3):

The equilibrium potential at any point in time is determined by the relative permeability of ions and the reversal potentials for those ions, according to the Goldman equation/GHK equation. The voltage of the cell moves towards that equilibrium potential at a rate that depends on the membrane time constant (determined by the capacitance and resistance/conductance of the membrane).

In a typical neuron, during the rising phase of an action potential, the conductance of sodium compared to other ions is very large, large enough that you can almost ignore the other ions, so the peak of the action potential gets fairly close to the sodium reversal potential. Often there is also permeability to calcium, which pushes it even closer to sodium reversal.

However, in cardiac pacemaker cells (and in cardiac myocytes), although there is a big increase in calcium permeability, the relative permeability to other ions isn't quite as big, so the "weighted average" of ion conductances and their reversal potentials gives an equilibrium potential somewhere in the middle.